# How do I declare a Chef file resource whose contents depend on cookbook files?

Tags: chef-infra

I need a file `fileC` deployed that's the concatenation of two other files `fileA` and `fileB`.  In my current setup, all three files are in the cookbook, declared as Cookbook File resources.

But it feels redundant.  I'd like to declare the bigger file as a function of the two others.

When `fileC` was first needed, I got it to "almost work" by luck by declaring the file resource's contents as `IO.read(file1) + IO.read(file2)`.  But that fails as soon as the recipe is deployed to a new node, since `fileA` and `fileB` aren't present at compile time.

I tried to access the underlying Ruby objects' information on where the cookbook could be deployed.  But the more I looked, the less I was convinced it was possible with my level of Chef/Ruby knowledge.  The resource↔provider gap seems too wide.

I'd like to avoid the `cat fileA fileB >fileC` type of solution, for the following reason: in the future, I'll likely need to disciminate nodes that need C from nodes that need A/B.

Any ideas on how to address the redundancy?

Comment: (posted on SO instead of SF because it feels more like programming than actual admin)

Answer (score 5):

If you used a template, I think you could get away with it. e.g.

```
template "/var/tmp/fileC.txt" do
   source "fileC.erb"
   variables(:included_files => ["/var/tmp/file1.txt", "/var/tmp/file2.txt"])
end
```

And then in your template

```
<% @included_files.each { |file|  %>
<%= File.read(file) %>    
<% } %>
```

Comment: Looks promising.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I believe that this only works if the files are being copied to the node.  That being said you could always copy them to the cache path if they aren't being copied already..

Comment: @KevinCox you are correct. If you can live with placing the files as static templates you can work with partials and render.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.  Unfortunately it does involve a "cat" command, but the list of files is abstracted out into a list which can be set or modified using attributes:

```
files = ["foo", "bar"]    # Or retrieve from an attribute

execute "cat files" do
  command "cat #{files.map {|f| "/var/tmp/#{f} "}} > /var/tmp/foobar"
  action :nothing
end

files.each do |f|
  cookbook_file "/var/tmp/#{f}" do
    source f
    notifies :run, "execute[cat files]", :immediately
  end
end
```

I'm curious what the use case is here though.  My guess is two configuration fragments that need to be mashed together for a service that doesn't support a conf.d arrangement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm afraid it's not really what I had in mind, but I only blame myself for not conveying that properly.  Compared to your suggestion: I don't need abstraction over the number or names of the files; and I'd really like to someday not even deploy the partial files.  For questions: I'm not sure why you need the notification framework instead of just declaring the execute after the cookbook_files.  Isn't the resource order kept from the recipe?

Comment: My gut feeling is that I'd like compile-time access to `cookbook_file` contents so that I can declare a `file` contents from them.  Failing that, I suppose I could do with converge-time access to the cookbook_files' local location, and generate it with an `execute` or `ruby_block`.  I don't like cat and alike because they operate from the deployed files, and I don't want to count on them.

Comment: Please don't take this comment into account in any answer, I'm genuinely interested in better understanding of Chef resource management.  My use case is SSL certificate configuration: Apache wants the actual certificate and the intermediate certificate in separate files; while nginx want them concatenated in a single file.

Comment: The notification is needed so that if either foo or bar changes, then the cat command is re-run.  If there was just two cookbook_files followed by a cat, it would only ever be run once.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `:immediately`? Doesn't that trigger the run action an equal amount of times to the number of files that changed? Wouldn't it be preferred to use a deferred call to queue it up and only run a single time?